# Cómo agregar contenido a archivo txt sin borrar el existente en php

Tags: php

he estado intentado agregar un nuevo item a un txt en formato json desde php, ya intenté con array_push y funcionó la cuestión es que cada vez que se agrega uno nuevo la clave se inicia en 0, y quiero que tenga el valor de un string
aquí coloco un ejemplo de lo que deseo hacer:

```
$file=fopen('content.txt', 'r');
$d=fread($file,filesize('content.txt'));
$data=json_decode($d,true);
print_r($data);

{
    "Datos": {
        "Fecha": "2018-03-26",
        "Dato1": {
            "numero": "1",
            "valor": "80-82.9",
            "value": "92.8",
            "price": "70000"

        },
        "Dato2": {
            "numero": "1",
            "valor": "80-82.9",
            "value": "92.8",
            "price": "70000"
        }, 
        "Nuevo":{
         Aquí va el contenido del nuevo elemento, igual que los otros

    }
}
```

Así es como leo el archivo y para escribirlo uso fopen w, me sobreescribe todo el archivo y con el array push me lo agrega pero el valor de Dato2 empieza desde [0], ¿hay alguna manera de agregar un nuevo elemento debajo de Dato 2, y luego volver a guardar el txt con json_encode?, si me pudiesen ayudar se los agradecería,

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu técnica me parece algo extraña. Si he entendido bien ¿se trata de ir agregando trozos de JSON a tu archivo de texto? ¡ ?¿ ¿? ! ¿Qué código usas para escribir en el archivo?

Comment: Si has entendido bien, tengo un txt base y quiero ir añadiendole datos en trozos json como dices,

Comment: Si has entendido bien, tengo un txt base y quiero ir añadiendole datos en trozos json como dices, el código que uso es como data devuelve una matriz accedo a ella $data['datos'], este seria el valor del array $val=["numero"=>$numero, "valor"=>0,"value"=>0, "price"=>0]; array_push($data['Datos'],$val), después de esto escribo el archivo con $archivo=fopen('content.txt', 'w+');

fwrite($archivo,json_encode($data['Datos']));
fclose($archivo);

Comment: no se si sea la forma más adecuada, o si se sea posible agregar trozos de json como dices, solo se me ocurrió he intentado de todas las formas pero nada, si me pudieras sugerir una idea, te lo agradecería bastante

Comment: No es la mejor forma de hacerlo. Si fuera tú para este caso almacenaría esos datos en una base de datos, incluso optimizando, organizando cada cosa en tablas, etc, evitando así redundancia de datos si fuera el caso. En cuanto al código actual en sí, debes revisar la [documentación de `fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php), la función recibe un parámetro según el cual abrirá el fichero en un modo determinado. El modo `w+` ***coloca el puntero al fichero al principio del fichero y trunca el fichero a longitud cero***, tendrías que pasar ahí el modo `a` que escribe al final.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apunte revisaré la documentación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes usar `array_push` para añadir valores a un array asociativo (como el tuyo) porque no hay forma de saber cuál es el próximo elemento, eso funciona en arrays indexados.

Para añadir a tu array tendría que ser algo así como:

```
$data['Datos']['Dato3'] = array(
    'numero' => 1,
    'valor' => '80-82.9',
    'value' => 92.8,
    'price' => 70000
);
```

Pero ten en cuenta que no hay un orden. Dato2 no necesariamente después de Dato1, ni Dato3 será el último. Porque como ya te digo, no es un array indexado (con indices 0, 1, 2, 3, etc), sino asociativo (en tu caso asocia `Dato1` con esos valores, `Dato2` con otros valores, etc). En otros lenguajes de programación a esto lo llaman diccionario.

Con el código que tienes, querrás hacer algo así:

```
$file = fopen('content.txt', 'r'); // Abrir el archivo en modo lectura.
$d = fread($file, filesize('content.txt')); // Leer el archivo
fclose($file); // Cierras el archivo

$data = json_decode($d, true); // Decodificas los datos leídos

// Aquí podrías hacer lo que quieras con los datos, procesar, añadir, lo que sea.
// En este caso, añades nuevos datos.
$data['Datos']['Dato3'] = array(
    'numero' => 1,
    'valor' => '80-82.9',
    'value' => 92.8,
    'price' => 70000
);

// Cuando termines guardas los datos de nuevo en el archivo.
$file = fopen('content.txt', 'w'); // Abres el archivo en modo escritura.
fwrite($file, json_encode($data)); // Escribes los nuevos datos.
fclose($file); // Cierras el archivo.
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, por el apunte si es algo asi lo que quiero hacer en el txt, voy a intentar, tengo una duda puedo ir agregando nuevos datos dinamicamente?, esto es lo que me muestra la conversión con json_encode :    {"Datos":{"Dato3":{"numero":1,"valor":"80-82.9","value":92.8,"price":70000}}}

Comment: @TSistemas he editado mi respuesta. La idea es que lees el archivo y pasas los datos a una variable. Luego editas esa variable, y luego guardas la variable en el archivo de nuevo. Así deberías poder añadir datos dinámicamente.

Comment: Una duda. Al hacer: `$data['Datos']['Dato3'] = array(` no estas haciendo que $data valga ese nuevo valor y borre todo?. Creo que deberia ser .= no?

Comment: No. `$data['Datos']` ya existe, lo que no existe es `$data['Datos']['Dato3']`, al hacer `$data['Datos']['Dato3'] = array (...);` estamos asignando ese `array(...)` a un nuevo elemento `Dato3` del array `$data['Datos']`. Puedes ver cómo funciona aquí: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Comment: Si, efectivamente, ya lo logré muchas gracias!

Comment: @TSistemas si la respuesta es correcta márcala y así cerramos la pregunta. Espero haber ayudado.